# Firebase Snapshot Listener isn't detecting documentChanges

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a social media type of app in SwiftUI using Firebase as my backend. Basically, I am trying to create a messages page similar to Instagram DMs that shows the latest message for the group or DM. I am using a snapshot listener to do this. It works fine when the app is loaded, all of the latest messages are showing up in the scrollview, but if a new message is sent, no document change is documented.

My Firebase firestore is setup as such:

- Plans

  - 4705345
  - 4574395
  - 4753485
    - plan name
    - date posted
    - lastMessage
    - dateOfLastMessage
    - etc
    - messages
    - 34958734
    - 47593485

When a user sends a new message, it adds the message to the messages collection inside of the plan as well as updating the lastMessage and dateOfLastMessage. I am trying to get my snapshot listener to listen for the lastMessage and dateOfLastMessage to be modified so that it updates in my view.

```
firestoreListener2 = db.collection("Plans").whereField("usersThatLiked", arrayContains: String(uid)).order(by: "dateOfLastMessage", descending: true).addSnapshotListener{(snap, err) in
            
    if err != nil{
        return
    }
    
    for i in snap!.documentChanges{        
        print("\n\n plan document change \(i.type) \n\n")
        
        if i.type == .added{
            
            let id = i.document.documentID
            let name = i.document.get("planName") as! String
            let url = i.document.get("planURL") as! String
            let lastmsg = i.document.get("lastMessage") as! String
            let timestamp = i.document.get("dateOfLastMessage") as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date.now)
            let notifKey = i.document.get("notifKey") as? String ?? ""
            let sender = i.document.get("sender") as? Bool ?? true
            let read = i.document.get("read") as? Bool ?? true
            
            var recentIn = false
            
            for j in 0..<self.recents.count{                
                if self.recents[j].id == id {                    
                    recentIn = true                    
                }                
            }
            
            if(!recentIn){
                self.recents.append(Recent(id: id, name: name, url: url, lastmsg: lastmsg, timestamp: timestamp.dateValue(), notifKey: notifKey, sender: sender, read: read, isPlan: true))
            }
        }
        
        if i.type == .modified{
            
            let id = i.document.documentID
            let lastmsg = i.document.get("lastMessage") as! String
            let timestamp = i.document.get("dateOfLastMessage") as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date.now)
            
            for j in 0..<self.recents.count {                
                if self.recents[j].id == id{
                    self.recents[j].lastmsg = lastmsg
                    self.recents[j].timestamp = timestamp.dateValue()
                }                
            }
        }
        
        if i.type == .removed {                    
            let id = i.document.documentID
            
            for j in 0..<self.recents.count{                        
                if self.recents[j].id == id{
                    self.recents.remove(at: j)
                    return
                }                        
            }                    
        }                                
    }            
}
```